# Chat with modem during ppp connection

Tags: linux, networking, serial-port, ppp

I have a GPRS modem that I use with a PPP connection in an embedded Linux ; I need to get the modem hour while the connection is active, and for that I would like to use AT commands. But I have no idea how to send these commands to the modem...

I tryed with chat but it doesn't work the way I want, do you know how we can do this ? Send commands and get the return

Thanks !

Comment: What specific brand and model of modem?  How is the modem connected to your embedded system (i.e. USB, serial hardware, etc..)?

Comment: Don't known the specific brand/model sadly, but it's connected by serial ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make serial connections all day long from linux with PuTTY.  After you find which device the serial line is (as well as the baud rate/stop-bits/pairty/flow-control), then use the terminal and send your ascii `AT` commands.

Your terminal could be [`minicom`](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/), [`picocom`](http://code.google.com/p/picocom/), `putty` or the like.

If you like python, [`pyserial`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) is another option

Answer (score 2):

If your modem supports GSM07.11 multiplexer, then you may use it. 
One channel for pppd (or other ppp daemon) and other channel for AT commands.

Comment: I don't think it supports, sadly ; anyway, we can shut down the connexion but how can I do that by using chat ? Nothing seems to work for now :/